# Run Mongodb and Node using forever

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to Node Js and Mongodb. To start working with node and mongodb, everyday I need to start the services using,

```
sudo mongod
node server.js
```

Instead, I need a script or command that will automatically run on my server without any interruption. For that I used forever.I installed forever using,

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

After that, I have tried the following,

```
forever start -c ./usr/local/cellar/mongodb/2.6.6/bin/mongod/

forever start server.js
```

But it is not working. I have checked with

```
 forever list
```

it shows no forever process running.

Please help.

Comment: Dont run mongo using forever,make it as a service. But in case of node server.js you can use forever.. When you start server with forever whether it shows any error?

Comment: In case of node, no error is shown but the program is not working when I run using Postman Client. For mongodb , can you give me an example please

Comment: Can you post what is shown in the console when you ran forever server.js??

Comment: Forever for node is working fine now. How can I use service for Mongodb?

Comment: how do you installed mongo,whether using source zip.. If you followed the tutorial `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04` its by default as service

Comment: I already installed mongodb using npm install. How can I use the above link now?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Subbaraj, forever can't be used to start a service like mongodb. Forever is meant to run nodejs server continuously even if it is terminated due to some bug/error in implementation. You have mentioned that you have installed mongodb using npm, which is just a connector to mongodb from nodejs. Firstly you must install mongodb with the help of link 
https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Subbaraj, forever can't be used to start a service like mongodb. Forever is meant to run nodejs server continuously even if it is terminated due to some bug/error in implementation. You have mentioned that you have installed mongodb using npm, which is just a connector to mongodb from nodejs. Firstly you must install mongodb with the help of link Subbarj had provided. For your reference again posting it here : https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/